# Corrected procedure to contact a user who does not write in chat

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, users

Is there a way to contact or ping a TeX.SE user who does not use the chat  to send a private message, or comment?

What is the correct procedure?

Comment: You *could* leave a comment under one of the post of this user. However, I feel that this is not something you should do. Rather, you should respect the decision of users not to participate in the chat. That is, if the comment goes beyond the purpose of usual comments, i.e. improving the post written by the user, you should *not* post it. Some users simply do not want to be contacted that way.

Comment: There is quite deliberately no user-to-user communication on the network, other than for mod messages

Comment: @Alan Munn I have accepted the duplicated question.